# How do i send a SMS using phonegap without opening the native app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I am making an SMS app using HTML,CSS, and JAVASCRIPT on intel xdk.
I have tried quite a few SMS phonegap plugins, but all open the native SMS app and the user has to click send again.

Is there anyway i can send the SMS using the above coding languages but without opening the default SMS app?

EDIT : Surprisingly, just moments after posting this question. I found this
[CORDOVA SMS PLUGIN](https://github.com/hazems/cordova-sms-plugin)
I'm yet to check if it works.
Meanwhile, is there any other method too?

Comment: You could try to find SMS plugin that use MFMessageComposeViewController. The controller is used to send SMS without using UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that plugin (https://github.com/hazems/cordova-sms-plugin) and it worked for me.  I can't endorse it, but I was able to send a text message without going into the SMS app, though it does show the message in my history of messages in the SMS app.

I just included the plugin as a third party plugin on the projects page and used this code (with a valid number in place of the Xs) :

```
var mymsg = {
    phoneNumber: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    textMessage: "Testing"
}

if (typeof sms === 'undefined' || typeof sms.sendMessage !== 'function') {
    alert("No plugin");
}
sms.sendMessage(mymsg, function(message) {
    console.log("success: " + message);
    alert("Sent");
}, function(error) {
    console.log("code: " + error.code + ", message: " + error.message);
    alert("Error sending");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it and works for me. So if i have to send an SMS to a person in another country, do i just enter the number or countrycode + number?

Comment: I would assume you'd just use the same number you'd use if you were sending it by hand, so yes, but I'm not sure if it's covered in my Cell plan so I'm afraid to try :-)

Comment: haha. yeah. Maybe i'll try it on someone who's got a postpaid plan, so they won't screw me for international charges immediately